# How to fix - Object "Inputs2' not found. And get the final plot in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am new to building apps in RStudio Shiny. I have checked everything in my following code and it seems to be working all the way up to plotting, however I can't get any plot and the server window gives an error: "Object 'Inputs2' not found." Any help will be appreciated with the code. And my final goal is to get the plot.

```
library(shiny)
library(Benchmarking)
library(plotly)

# load data 
maindata <- read.csv("raw.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",


# Application title
titlePanel("Preferred Usage"),

# Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    h3("Enter Inputs",""),
    numericInput("qout1", "Output 1","0"),
    numericInput("qout2", "Output 2","0"),
    numericInput("qin1", "Input 1","0"),
    numericInput("qin2", "Input 2","0"),
    numericInput("qin3", "Input 3","0"),
    numericInput("pin1", "Price Input 1","0"),
    numericInput("pin2", "Price Input 2","0"),
    numericInput("pin3", "Price Input 3","0"),
    actionButton("runButton", "Run Analysis")


  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
     plotOutput("coolplot")

   )
 )
)
```

An the server side code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {


# The important part of reactiveValues()
values <- reactiveValues()
grph <- reactiveValues()
values$df <- maindata 
addData <- observe({

# your action button condition
if(input$runButton > 0) {
  # create the new line to be added from your inputs
  newLine <- isolate(c(input$qout1, input$qout2, input$qin1, input$qin2, input$qin3, input$pin1, input$pin2, input$pin3))
  # update your data
  # note the unlist of newLine, this prevents a bothersome warning message that the rbind will return regarding rownames because of using isolate.
  table1 <- isolate(values$df <- rbind(unlist(newLine), as.matrix(values$df)))



  # inputs and outputs for analysis
  y <- data.frame(table1[, 1:2])
  x <- data.frame(table1[, 3:5])
  w <- data.frame(table1[, 6:8])



  # function to do some analysis
  xopt <- cost.opt(x, y, w, RTS=1)

  # Fetch results
  results <- data.frame(xopt[["xopt"]])
  results[1,]

  #Prepare data for plotting 
  Inputs <- c("Seed", "Fertilizer", "Power")
  Inputs2 <- as.numeric(c(x[1,]))
  Inputs3 <-  as.numeric(c(results[1,]))

  isolate(grph$try1 <- rbind(Inputs, Inputs2, Inputs3))

  grph$try1 <- data.frame(t(grph$try1))

}

})



output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({p <- plot_ly(data.frame(grph$try1), x = ~Inputs, y = ~Inputs2, type = 'bar', text = round(Inputs2, 2), textposition = 'auto', name = 'Inputs2', marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)')) %>%
add_trace(y = ~Inputs3, text = round(Inputs3, 2), textposition = 'auto', name = 'Inputs3', marker = list(color = 'rgb(49,130,189)')) %>%
layout(title = "Plot", barmode = 'group', yaxis = list(title = "Count"))})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Reproducible Data Samples from the above work:

1- the "raw.csv" with initial 5 rows

```
structure(list(qout1 = c(6.278, 7.345, 6.609, 6.141, 8.653), 
qout2 = c(4.399, 5.423, 4.787, 3.947, 5.492), qin1 = c(1.719, 
3.422, 2.585, 2.308, 2.717), qin2 = c(0.891, 1.663, 1.018, 
1.484, 1.54), qin3 = c(0.906, 0.742, 0.826, 1.406, 1.621), 
pin1 = c(1.798, 0.675, 0.743, 1.76, 1.774), pin2 = c(3.377, 
2.871, 4.857, 3.19, 3.283), pin3 = c(6.42, 8.997, 9.13, 6.136, 
6.205)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

2- the "table1" data from the server side code, first five rows. first row is zero for all variables because new input data was all zero:

```
structure(c(0, 6.278, 7.345, 6.609, 6.141, 0, 4.399, 5.423, 4.787, 
3.947, 0, 1.719, 3.422, 2.585, 2.308, 0, 0.891, 1.663, 1.018, 
1.484, 0, 0.906, 0.742, 0.826, 1.406, 0, 1.798, 0.675, 0.743, 
1.76, 0, 3.377, 2.871, 4.857, 3.19, 0, 6.42, 8.997, 9.13, 6.136
), .Dim = c(5L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("qout1", "qout2", 
"qin1", "qin2", "qin3", "pin1", "pin2", "pin3"))
```

3- Finally, the "grph$try1" data that is fed to plotly for analysis is as such, first five rows:

```
structure(list(Inputs = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA), .Label = 
c("Fertilizer", "Power", "Seed"), class = "factor"), Inputs2 = 
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "0", class = "factor"), 
Inputs3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "0", class = 
"factor")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "NA", "NA.1"), class = 
"data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your first problem is that the plot is rendered before the `grph$try1` is calculated. You can avoid this quite easily by including a `req` statment like this

```
output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
      req(!is.null(grph$try1))
      p <- plot_ly(
                   ...
)})
```

you also want to change the ui from `plotOutput` to `plotlyOutput`.

Since you want to access the diffentent Inputs from the data.frame I think you are better off initiating the `grph$try1` directly as a data.frame like this

```
isolate(grph$try1 <- data.frame(Inputs, Inputs2, Inputs3))
```

you will also need to add `~` before the round functions other wise plotly doesn't now it has to evalute them inside. The plotly call the finally looks like this

```
p <- plot_ly(grph$try1, 
             x = ~Inputs,
             y = ~Inputs2, 
             type = 'bar',
             text = ~round(Inputs2, 2),
             textposition = 'auto', name = 'Inputs2', marker = list(color = 'rgb(204,204,204)')) %>%
      add_trace(y = ~Inputs3,
                text = ~round(Inputs3, 2), 
                textposition = 'auto', 
                name = 'Inputs3',
                marker = list(color = 'rgb(49,130,189)')) %>%
      layout(title = "Plot", barmode = 'group', yaxis = list(title = "Count"))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Bertil for your time! This was very helpful. Everything is resolved now. I had to disable this part of code:  `grph$try1 <- data.frame(t(grph$try1))`  because it was creating additional problems.